# print the log and store the log at the sametime, what's wrong with my code?

Tags: python, logging

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os 
import logging
import pickle

def _config_logger(test_name):
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(message)s',filename="./%s.txt" %(test_name))
    stderrLogger=logging.StreamHandler()
    stderrLogger.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(message)s'))
    logging.getLogger("").addHandler(stderrLogger)
    return logger

for i in ['x','y','z']:
    logger=_config_logger(i)
    logger.debug(i)
```

The output is not expected, y print twice, z print 3 times.

$ python test.py
x
y
y
z
z
z

But I only got one file x.txt, I expect y.txt. z.txt is there

$ ls
test.py  x.txt

how should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Check the docs for [logging.basicConfig](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig):

> This function does nothing if the root logger already has handlers
>   configured for it.

After you called it once to log to for `x.txt`, the subsequent calls have no effect.

Instead of calling `logging.basicConfig`, add a file handler similar to how you're adding a stream handler:

```
file_handler = logging.FileHandler("./%s.txt" %test_name)
file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
def _config_logger(test_name):
    logger = logging.getLogger()
```

you don't pass `test_name` to `geLogger()`, so you're always getting the root logger. And a couple lines later:

```
logging.getLogger("").addHandler(stderrLogger)
```

you keep on adding handlers to the root logger, hence the "y print twice, z print 3 times" symptom.

Also, calling `.basicConfig()` more than once is useless and only the first call is relevant, cf [the fine manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig):

> Does basic configuration for the logging system by creating a StreamHandler with a default Formatter and adding it to the root logger. The functions debug(), info(), warning(), error() and critical() will call basicConfig() automatically if no handlers are defined for the root logger.
>
> This function does nothing if the root logger already has handlers  configured for it.